# How to make image height certain percentage of containing text div?

Tags: css, image, responsive

There is a div has an image and some text in it. The containing div doesn't have a specific height and is dependent on the text within the div.

I'm using the following css for the image and containing div:

```
.Image{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 70%;
    margin-right: 1em;
    border: 0;
}
.DivBlock{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

However, since the div doesn't have a height specified the image height doesn't adjust according to the outer div. How do I adjust this to make it to only 70% of the height of the containing div?

Find below entire code:

```css
.Image{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 70%;
    margin-right: 1em;
    border: 0;
}
.DivBlock{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h3>History:</h3>
<div class="DivBlock">
    <img class="Image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/09/00/55/lotus-978659__340.jpg" />
    <p>Matheran was identified by Hugh Poyntz Malet, the then district collector of Thane district in May 1850. Lord Elphinstone, the then Governor of Bombay laid the foundations of the development as a future hill station. The British developed Matheran as a resort to beat the summer heat in the region.</p>
    <p>Matheran is the birthplace of freedom fighter Veer Bhai Kotwal. He was born on 1 December 1912 in a Barber family. The state government has built a monument in his memory. The Matheran Hill Railway was built in 1907 by Sir Adamjee Peerbhoy and covers a distance of 20 km (12 mi), over large swathes of forest territory.</p>
    <p>The Matheran hill railway, also known as Matheran Light Railway (MLR), was inspected by UNESCO world heritage site officials but failed to make it to the list as a World Heritage Site. India's other Hill Railways like the Darjeeling Railway, the Kangra Valley Railway, Nilgiri Mountain Railway are already on the list.</p>
</div>
```

Also find jsfiddle for the same:
https://jsfiddle.net/mithunu/tu25y6da/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap image inside 'div' tag and add min-height to it.

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img class="Image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/09/00/55/lotus-978659__340.jpg" />
</div>
<style>
    .img-wrapper{
        display:inline-block;
        min-height:70%;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `img` in a container with a specific height. Pourcent works only if it refers to a specific height. If your you height could be dynamic you can use some JS to get the height of your bloc text for example.

```css
.container-img {
  min-height: 340px;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 1em;
}


.Image {
  max-height: 70%;
  border: 0;
}

.DivBlock {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h3>History:</h3>
<div class="DivBlock">
  <div class="container-img">
   <img class="Image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/09/00/55/lotus-978659__340.jpg" />
  </div>
  <p>Matheran was identified by Hugh Poyntz Malet, the then district collector of Thane district in May 1850. Lord Elphinstone, the then Governor of Bombay laid the foundations of the development as a future hill station. The British developed Matheran as a resort to beat the summer heat in the region.</p>
  <p>Matheran is the birthplace of freedom fighter Veer Bhai Kotwal. He was born on 1 December 1912 in a Barber family. The state government has built a monument in his memory. The Matheran Hill Railway was built in 1907 by Sir Adamjee Peerbhoy and covers a distance of 20 km (12 mi), over large swathes of forest territory.</p>
  <p>The Matheran hill railway, also known as Matheran Light Railway (MLR), was inspected by UNESCO world heritage site officials but failed to make it to the list as a World Heritage Site. India's other Hill Railways like the Darjeeling Railway, the Kangra Valley Railway, Nilgiri Mountain Railway are already on the list.</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2ykovaxr/